# Lotus Notes: Dialog list multiple column display

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I'm trying to perform a multiple column view in a dialog list prompt using a `@DbColumn` command and did that successfully by adding another column in a view where my dialog list is looking up. The column value in it is something like this: `SiteNum + SiteName + State`, a combination of my first 3 columns.

Now, is there any way that I can only select "SiteNum" column and have that as my dialog list field value?

I got it working with the help of @Richard and @Ken. I made my formula like this, `SiteNum + SiteName + State + "|" + SiteNum`. But the problem is that when I select one, the SiteNum only stores on the backend and the field displays the whole selection (e.g `0006-USNY`) it should only be the SiteNum (e.g `0006`)

I hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set your formula to SiteNum + SiteName + State + "|" + SiteNum. That will tell the dialog lis to display SiteNum + SiteName + State but return the alias value SiteNum.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, I've tried that since Ken answered the same like yours, but it still doesn't get the SiteNum, am I missing a key tweak in my field property? or in my view column property maybe?

Comment: How did you set the field properties? What is your exact formula for the @DBColumn? What is the exact formula for the column you return? Is the property "Allow keyword Synonyms" of the field set?

Comment: Here's the formula for my @DbColumn..
`@Unique(@DbColumn("" : "NoCache"; @DbName; "SiteLookupView"; 4))`.
And the formula for in the Column Value is..
`SiteNum + SiteName + State + "|" + SiteNum`. The "Allow keyword Synonyms" is checked.

Comment: Also, when I clicked the dialog list the popup window displays like this.. `0000TestNY|0000` the SiteNum displays also instead of being an alias (SiteNumSiteNameState|SiteNum).

Comment: Okay, I got, it actually works but it only store in the backend that's why I didn't see it. Is there anyway that I can display it instantly when selected besides creating a "Computed for display" field?